# Switching iframes with Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to use `selenium` to navigate a website that is using frames.

Here is my working python script for part 1:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from urllib import request

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.lgs-hosted.com/rmtelldck.html')

driver.switch_to.frame('menu')

driver.execute_script('xSubmit()')

time.sleep(.5)

link = driver.find_element_by_id('ml1T2')
link.click()
```

Here is the page element:

```
<html webdriver="true">
    <head></head>
    <frameset id="menuframe" name="menuframe" border="0" frameborder="0" cols="170,*">
        <frameset border="0" frameborder="0" rows="0,*">
            <frame scrolling="AUTO" noresize="" frameborder="NO" src="heart.html" name="heart"></frame>
            <frame scrolling="AUTO" noresize="" frameborder="NO" src="rmtelldcklogin.html" name="menu"></frame>
        </frameset>
        <frame scrolling="AUTO" noresize="" frameborder="NO" src="rmtelldcklogo.html" name="update"></frame>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

My issue is switching the frames...its in 'menu' I need to get into 'update':

```
driver.switch_to.frame('update')
```

^ does not work....error tells me its not there, even though we can clearly see it is...any ideas?

How do I switch from `menu` to `update`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *switch back to the default content* before switching to a different frame:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame("update")

# to prove it is working
title = driver.find_element_by_id("L_DOCTITLE").text
print(title)
```

Prints:

```
Civil Case Inquiry
```

Comment: Ya know...I worked on this for 2 days...and I swear I tried that....thank you that worked flawlessly!