# How to select an input that is inside a frameset - webdriver selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to select an input that have framesets and frame inside it. I cant select inputs because they appears to be inside a frame. So how i can recognize the frames and change into it? so i can select the inputs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching iframes with Python/Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466485/switching-iframes-with-python-selenium)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to), it's as simple as:

`driver.switch_to.frame(‘frame_name’)`

Or, you can use the frame's index:

`driver.switch_to.frame(1)`

You can even use any of the `find_elements` functions:

`driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name(“iframe”)[0])`

If you want to then return to the default content, you can simply call:

`driver.switch_to.default_content()`